# Pass Multiple Values and Get Selected Results In A Cell

Tags: excel, vba, formula, excel-2013

I am new with `Excel VBA` and trying to use it for a scenario in an `Excel` work book. I am trying to do a multiple value search in a cell and that should be highlighted. Say I've these ids - 1001, 1002, so in the specific cell these values should be highlighted or searched. I am not sure how can I use `List<>` in `VBA` but in `C#`, I can do the following:

```
List<string> aLst = new List<string>();
aLst.Add("1001");
aLst.Add("1002");
```

So with the list, I can iterate the ids and get the results matched. I was looking into the following `VBA` code and it gets one value as parameter. Then checks the matched one:

```
Function SingleCellExtract(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer)
Dim i As Long
Dim Result As String
For i = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count

If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
  Result = Result & " " & LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & ","
  End If
  Next i
  SingleCellExtract = Left(Result, Len(Result) – 1)
End Function
```

Here is the link that I am following: [Excel VBA](https://trumpexcel.com/multiple-lookup-values-single-cell-excel/)
So any way that I can use `List<>` and search the required values highlighted in the excel sheet?

**Sample**:

```
Id   -   Name
1001     John
1002     Jack
```

Comment: Nope, but you can use a Dictionary or an array to essentially perform the same function. Alternatively, you can use a range in a sheet to get your list of values. The above example looks to be using a range. Depends if you want to hardcode things or not. Bottom line, VBA is not C# and it’s also not VB.NET ... it’s not packed with as many features but doesn’t stop you from getting the result you need.

Comment: if you post a sample of how your data is structured, we could better lead you to get a better solution

Comment: It's simple and given in the post @Ricardo Diaz. I just require to retrieve multiple values on search or just highlighted the default way in the excel file.

Answer (score 1):

So copy this function into a new module.

Then you can access either via another function or procedure or through an excel formula in a cell like =MultiCellExtract(A2:A3;A2:B3;2)

```
' LookupValuesRange is an Excel Range of cells
Public Function MultiCellExtract(LookupValuesRange As Range, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer) As String

    Dim cellValue As Range

    Dim i As Long
    Dim Result As String

    For Each cellValue In LookupValuesRange

        For i = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count

            If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = cellValue.Value Then
                Result = Result & " " & LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & ","
            End If

        Next i

    Next cellValue

    MultiCellExtract = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)

End Function
```

Let me know if it helps or we can adjust it.